# Spring JPA Unable To Find Composite Foreign Key Target Column (Non-PK)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserRole userRole;

}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

}
```

**Client.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "user_role_id") })
    private User user;

}
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: user_role_id in users
```

**In RDBMS, users.(id, user_role_id) is unique so clients table can refer to that.**

Last time, I was using `insertable = false, updatable = false` on `user_role_id`, but when I want to add records of new client, I always need to add `user_role_id` manually `user.setUserRoleId(userRole.getId())` after `user.setUserRole(userRole)` and I think that is bad practice of ORM (it should be added automatically when I set `user.setUserRole(userRole)`)

```
@Column(name = "user_role_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer userRoleId;
```

What should I do so the relation can be mapped in Spring JPA? and what is the best practice?

In other words, this is also mean how to reference to foreign key generated logical name column?

Comment: Either it should be id or user_role_id

Comment: @SimonMartinelli what do you mean?

Comment: Now you've updated your question and it's no longer wrong

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yeah, my bad I just copied my experimental code before, now it is updated and still do not know why it is happen

Comment: the error says that there is no column with the name user_role_id

Comment: @SimonMartinelli but there is `@JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id"...` in User.java

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar are you looking for solution that specifically use this mechanism as mentioned in your question (*Composite Foreign Key Target Column (Non-PK)*)? Or other solution that would work will be also fine? 
I was able to configure your case to work as expected (mapping user with his role by one assignment), but reading this composite FK indeed was not possible for me to achieve

Comment: @pan-leszeczek every solution is welcome, but must be hold referential integrity from user, user_role, and also client table

Comment: What is your version of JPA, Hibernate, Spring Boot? What is your database? version? Java version?

Comment: @JamesGraham 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: I've added another answer which fits best in my opinion. I'm leaving this one as well to see the other steps I tried.

Though the solution is not elegant and not using JPA as requested. Just in case anything in here would be helpful

If I understand the main issue correctly - you want to bind *Client* entity with *Role* entity via *User* entity, by first setting User's Role and then transfer that "property" by using only *UserId* instead setting additionally *RoleId* while creating *Client*.

Basically after playing for a while with your model I think the main issue is to assign data to each other within a `@Transactional` methods. That seems to be caused ba Lazy fetch strategy.
My proposal for solution that binds all your Entities according expectations differs only from yours with ommiting the ***RoleId*** JoinColumn in `Clients` table. I have checked that when calling a service that would have `@Transactional` methods, you can assign a *Role* to the *User* and *User* to the *Client* with simple `user.setRole(roleEntity)` followed by `client.setUser(userEntity)`.
All the data is then consistent. No need to call further like getters and setters as you mentioned in the second part of your question. 
Question is if for any reason you need to have `RoleId` as well in your `Clients` Table, then this soultion would have to be enhanced by additional column?

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Integer roleId;

//getters and setters and toString
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")
private UserRole userRole;;

//getters and setters and toString;
}
```

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "client_id")
private Integer clientId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
})
private User user;

@Column(name = "client_role_id")
private Integer roleId;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void prePersist(){
    try {
        roleId = getUser().getUserRole().getRoleId();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        roleId = null;
    }
}

//getters and setters and toString

}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
UserRepo userRepo;

public UserService(UserRepo userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

@Transactional
public void save(User user) {
    userRepo.save(user);
}

@Transactional
public User getReferenceById(int i) {
    return userRepo.getReferenceById(i);
}
}
```

**ClientService.java**

```
@Service
public class ClientService {
private ClientRepo clientRepo;
private UserService userService;

public ClientService(ClientRepo clientRepo, UserService userService) {
    this.clientRepo = clientRepo;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Transactional
public Client save(Client client){
    return clientRepo.save(client);
}

@Transactional
public Client getReferenceById(int i) {
    return clientRepo.getReferenceById(i);
}

@Transactional
public void printClient(Client client){
    client = clientRepo.getReferenceById(client.getClientId());
    System.out.println(client);
}

@Transactional
public void bindUserToClient(int userId, int clientId) {
    Client entity = clientRepo.findById(clientId).orElseGet(Client::new);
    entity.setUser(userService.getReferenceById(userId));
}

@Transactional
public void printClient(int i) {
    clientRepo.findById(i).ifPresentOrElse(this::printClient, EntityNotFoundException::new);
}
}
```

This configuration after running this commandLineRunner:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean
@Transactional
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(
        @Autowired UserRoleRepo roleRepo,
        @Autowired UserService userService,
        @Autowired ClientService clientService
) {
    return args -> {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            roleRepo.save(new UserRole());
        }

        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserRole(roleRepo.getReferenceById(i));
            userService.save(user);
        }

        Client client = new Client();
        client.setUser(userService.getReferenceById(2));
        client = clientService.save(client);
        clientService.printClient(client);

        client = new Client();
        client.setClientId(1);
        clientService.printClient(client);
        int userId = 5;
        clientService.bindUserToClient(userId, 1);
        clientService.printClient(1);
    };
}
}
```

gave me correct output in the console:

```
Client{id=1, user=User{id=2, userRole=UserRole{id=4}}}
Client{id=1, user=User{id=2, userRole=UserRole{id=4}}}
Client{id=1, user=User{id=5, userRole=UserRole{id=1}}}
```

### WORKAROUND

I tried to reach the goal by use of Spring JPA but could'nt.
The workaround that keeps the referential integrity was by creating a constrains through DB like below and add `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotated method which is updating the client's roleId as intended.

```
create table clients
(
    client_id      integer not null,
    client_user_id integer,
    client_role_id integer,
    primary key (client_id)
);
create table user_roles
(
    role_id integer generated by default as identity,
    primary key (role_id)
);
create table users
(
    user_id      integer generated by default as identity,
    user_role_id integer,
    primary key (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT User_Role UNIQUE (user_id, user_role_id)
);
alter table users
    add constraint FK_role_id foreign key (user_role_id) references user_roles (role_id);
alter table clients
    add constraint FK_user_id foreign key (client_user_id, client_role_id) references users (user_id, user_role_id) on update cascade ;
```

Thanks to that I could for instance update `userRole` in `user` entity, and the change was reflected in the `clients` table as well without any further actions

Comment: user_role_id in Client table is used for referential integrity from User table, to make sure user_role_id that selected in User table is Client Role and to be checked in Client table (ex: CHECK user_role_id = 1), so the user_role_id in Client table is a must.

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar I've posted another answer that should meet all your expectations. Referential integrity is kept and the Client table has both columns :)

Answer (score 0):

OK! Please try following configuration:
Below is a important code part and under [this link](https://github.com/Lesjad/jpa-fk-configuration/tree/master) you may find repository with working example

***UserRole.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;
}
```

***User.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")
    private UserRole userRole;
}
```

***Client.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private Integer clientId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
            value = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "client_role_id", referencedColumnName = "user_role_id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "client_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            }
            ,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "FK_user_with_role",
                    foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (client_user_id, client_role_id)\n" +
            "   REFERENCES users \n" +
            "       (user_id, user_role_id) \n" +
            "   ON UPDATE CASCADE\n" +
            "   ON DELETE CASCADE")
    )
    private User user;
}
```

Please note that beside adding a foreignKey in the `Client` implementation, you **MUST** keep the sequence of `@JoinColum` annotations.. I don't know what is the reason behind, but if you flip those lines you'll still get your error as it was before :)

Comment: I just want to map the existing database to ORM, isn't this used for migration?

Comment: well, proposed model will work If all constrains are defined in the database. If DB is defined for instance simply by creating tables with column names that match but without references then it will not create any changes in the database constrains -> thus it will not keep the referential integrity